# Icon not displaying on android screen using react-native-vector-icons

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I am new to react-native and[image] trying to implement tab navigator. I am using react-native-vector-icons. i tried to display icon in my screen but It isn't showing me any icon.Here is what I did

> 1-npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
>
> 2-react-native link react-native-vector-icons
>
> 3-Edited android/app/build.gradle

```
  project.ext.vectoricons = [
        iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] 
    ]
  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

> 4- react-native run-android

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Image,StatusBar,Button,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import profile from './profile';

export  class test extends Component
{ render()
    { 
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>Test</Text>
                 </View>
             );
    }
}
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
'test':{screen:test,
navigationOption:{
tabBarLabel:'test',
tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
<Icon name="rocket" color={tintColor} size={40}/>
 )}},
 'Profile': { screen:profile,
    navigationOption:{
        tabBarLabel:'profile',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor})=>(
            <Icon name="rocket" color={tintColor} size={40}/>
) } }     
},{

    navigationOption:{
        tabBarVisible:true
    },   
    tabBarOptions:{
        activeTintColor:'red',
        inactiveTintColor:'grey'
    }
});

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
                 flexGrow:1,

                  backgroundColor:'#1c313a',
                justifyContent:'center',
                alignItems:'center'
              },
                text:{
                fontSize:25,
                fontWeight:'500',
                color :'#fff',
                paddingHorizontal:16 ,
                textAlign:'center'
               }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the name `rocket` for icon type `Ionicons`, don't exist.
You can check that here

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Maybe you would use another type or another name.

Comment: You use `Icon` from `react-native-vector-icons`, try using `Icon` from `react-native-elements`, its works for me always. [https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements]

Comment: its working now, there was a spelling mistake. change navigationOption to navigationOptions.